# Simultaneous probability distribution

Tags: probability

Just starting to learn probability and would appreciate if someone could explain how this type of questions are done.

I have the following simultaneos probability function:

```
p-X,Y(x,y)  0     1        2
0          0.1   0.2      0.1
1          0.2   0.3      0.1
```

What is P(Y>0∣X=1)?

Comment: Which one is $X$ ? The rows or the columns? In other words, what is the maximum value of $X$ ?

Comment: @MattiP. Oh sorry, X has the values 0, 1 and 2, and Y has 0 and 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think X is the variable in column. If not, use the same but reversed procedure.

In order to respond to the question, use the definition

$\mathbb{P}[Y>0|X=1]=\frac{\mathbb{P}[Y>0;X=1]}{\mathbb{P}[X=1]}=\frac{0.3+0.1}{0.6}=\frac{4}{6}$

Comment: Thanks for this. X has the values 0, 1 and 2, and Y has 0 and 1. So Im just going to do the reversed procedure

Comment: Im getting that P(Y>0|X=1) is 0.1+0.2 = 0.3 and P(x) is 0.5. Is that true?

Comment: Yes and NO. The result of $\frac{3}{5}$ is ok but it is a chance. $\mathbb{P}[Y>0;X=1]=\mathbb{P}[Y=1;X=1]=0.3$